# Intellj Idea python tool - No pytest runner found in selected interpreter

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Intellj Idea integrated tool says **No pytest runner found in selected interpreter** even after python plugin has been installed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Let the project indexing and Python interpreter update complete. At some point, the pytest gets enabled.

Intellj indexing takes too long so need to be extra patient, or switch to another IDE.

[image]